# How to reload initializer for each record update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reload, initializer

In my application I am using one global variable which is defined in config/initializers/details.rb

```
$available_plans= Plan.all
```

and using this variable, all over the application and this will be available to all  users. If I add one more plan, that should be reflected automatically, so I need to reload initializer

so after_create added a method to reload the initializer,

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_file "config/initializers/details.rb"
```

is this the right way ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. It should be asked on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create: custom_method

  # Whatever code      

  private
  def custom_method
    $available_plans= Plan.all
  end
end
```

Also, when a plan is edited that should be reflected in the global variable, so we should use `after_save` instead:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save: custom_method

  # Whatever code      

  private
  def custom_method
    $available_plans= Plan.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Tamer, I can follow this way, but if I want to get the plan details in a global variable($user_plan = current_user.plan_deails) is it correct?

Comment: In fact, using global variables is not convenient in Rails. I don't think you should use a global variable for a plan details, it's needed only for the current user, isn't it?

Comment: Yes but, to avoid calling it each and every activity to set the privilege, if I set it as global I can just use that

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle this is to forgo the initializer and global variables entirely. This, to my eye, is more localized and cleaner.

First, in your Plan class, add a caching method to access all the plans:

```
def self.available_plans
    @available_plans ||= Plan.all
end
```

Note: This can be improved using the [cached_method gem](https://github.com/seamusabshere/cache_method) which will let you cache the plans across app instances etc... if that is important to you.

Now you can access your plans throughout the code like this:

```
Plan.available_plans
```

The first time this is called in an app instance, the plans will be loaded. Every time thereafter it will return the original results.

Finally, when plans are added, removed, or modified (again, in your Plan model):

```
after_save :expire_cached_available_plans
after_destroy :expire_cached_available_plans

...

private
def expire_cached_available_plans
   self.class.instance_variable_set("@available_plans", nil)
end
```

Now whenever you create, update, or destroy an Plan object, the cached plans will be cleared. The next time you call Plan.available_plans, it will fetch (and cache) a fresh list.